# Subtracts A from B

Tags: meaning, numbers, mathematics

This is quite an embarrassing question, but what does it mean subtracting A from B?

1. `B - A` (correct, in my opinion)
2. `A - B`

I got a bit confused and I wouldn't err all the exercise because of this little confusion.

Comment: If you are subtracting a from b, then you are taking away a from b, or mathematically subtracting a is the same as adding the opposite of a, ie b + (-a) = b - a.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct *(Both linguistically and mathematically)*

We start with **B** and remove **A**

Answer (score 3):

"Subtract A from B" means "From B, subtract A", which equals "B - A".

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that subtracting A FROM B means you are taking away A **FROM** B. It's the opposite of adding A **TO** B. You ADD something TO something else; you SUBTRACT something FROM something else.